# PKIX Path Building failed after upgrading from 0.9.6 to 1.0.x karate version

Tags: java, ssl, karate

I was trying to upgrade our working Karate tests from the 0.9.6 karate version to the 1.0.x version.  I have defined the Keystores and truststores in the feature file using the ssl configuration and they work fine in the 0.9.6 version of karate.  When I change to utilize the 1.0.x version of karate, I receive a PKIX Path Building failure:

> javax.net.ssl|ERROR|1B|pool-1-thread-1|2021-05-22 17:18:20.212
> CDT|TransportContext.java:318|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target ( "throwable" : {
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I've added breakpoints in the karate ApacheHttpClient class and I can see that the Keystore and TrustStores are being set, as well as verifying that the trusted certs are being added as trusted certificates when running with -Djavax.net.debug=all.

I've even added the specific server cert that is being sent to the trust store.  I cannot seem to find the root cause  of why I am receiving a PKIX failure on the 1.0.x version of karate, yet the exact same configuration works fine in the 0.9.6 version.  I have also validated the CAs from the full chain of the server cert being sent is included in my trust store.  It seems that maybe my trust store is being ignored once the request is sent.

Any thoughts about what might be different for TLS connections in karate 1.0.x?  As far as I can tell from the docs, the ssl configuration options have not changed.

---

Reproduced with Karate Demo: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/v1.0.1/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl

I made some tweaks to the karate demo SSL tests to show the issue with having Scenario Outline and the connectTimeout or readTimeout set:

karate-config.js:

```
function fn() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  var port = karate.properties['demo.server.port'] || '8080';
  var protocol = 'http';
  if (karate.properties['demo.server.https'] === 'true') {
    protocol = 'https';
    karate.configure('ssl', true);
  }
  var config = { demoBaseUrl: protocol + '://127.0.0.1:' + port };
  if (karate.env !== 'mock') {
    // karate.configure('callSingleCache', { minutes: 1 });
    // 'callSingle' is guaranteed to run only once even across all threads
    var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:demo/headers/common-noheaders.feature', config);
    // and it sets a variable called 'authInfo' used in headers-single.feature
    config.authInfo = { authTime: result.time, authToken: result.token };
  }
  config.applicationPaths = JSON.parse('[{"contextPath":"test"},{"contextPath":"test"}]')
  return config;
}
```

ssl-keystore.feature:

```
Feature: jersey ssl with trust store / cert

Background:
    * configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:server-keystore.p12', keyStorePassword: 'karate-mock', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12', trustStore: 'classpath:server-keystore.p12', trustStorePassword: 'karate-mock', trustStoreType: 'pkcs12' }
    * url 'https://localhost:' + karate.properties['jersey.ssl.port']

Scenario Outline:
    Given path '<contextPath>'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response == { success: true }
    Examples:
    | applicationPaths |
```

If you comment out the configs for the readTimeout and the connectTimeout in the karate-config.js, the test is successful.  With them uncommented, the test fails with a PKIX Path Building Failure.

Comment: I updated the post above to include changes that can be made to the Karate SSL demo to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing should have changed. I know this is hard, but please try to provide a sample for us to replicate.

We have a couple of tests that run in CI here - perhaps you can use them as a reference: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/v1.0.1/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl

Comment: Peter, I found my local issue was caused by setting the connectTimeout or the readTimeout in the karate-config.js AND using Scenario Outline to iterate on a scenario.  My local example does also have both the keystore, truststore, and algorithm set in the ssl configuration on the feature file.

Comment: @jcruse248 there is a bug on config getting reset for a scenario-outline,  hopefully it is that: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1560 -  you can confirm by trying 1.1.0.RC1

Comment: I have confirmed that the 1.1.0.RC1 version has resolved the issue.  Thanks for the help!